# Can we build authenticated encryption using Feistel Networks?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, feistel-network

Most of the encryption modes of Feistel Networks especially the ones used to build fixed length block ciphers just provide confidentiality .

Can we build authenticated encryption using Feistel Networks ?

Comment: One useful rule of thumb in cryptography is that even the meanest primitive can be used to build virtually everything. For example, you can take a PRG and build a PRF and PRP from that, and so on: pretty much, once you have a one-way function of some kind, you can build almost *everything* in symmetric cryptography. This is a pretty neat result, actually, since it boils down the whole of secure symmetric cryptography to the existence of one-way functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to build authenticated encryption using a Feistel Network is to build a Feistel based block cipher, then use one of the many modes of operation that turn a block cipher into an authenticated encryption scheme (eg [CCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode),[OCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CCM_mode),[GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode)).

For a good survey on the subject of modes-of-operation I would recommend [this paper](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/modes.pdf) by [Rogaway](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway). It does not cover the very most recent designs (such as those discussed at [DIAC'13](http://2013.diac.cr.yp.to/schedule.html)) but covers the more accepted methods in a reasonable amount of detail.

Comment: @pg1989 - Thanks for the edit, didn't realise I'd put the wrong link up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you certainly can. If you want a variable-length authenticated encryption mode, then simply take any Feistel cipher in the [OCB mode](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/ocb.pdf). If fixed-length is fine, then the following idea should work. Build a wide Feistel-based permutation (fixed-key blockcipher) $G$ and encrypt
$$
C = G(P||N||K)\oplus K,
$$
where $N$ is nonce, $P$ is plaintext, $C$ is ciphertext, $K$ is key.